# How do I get persistence with AKKA for MySQL using the Java API?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, akka

Since the AKKA persistence module has been deprecated, how can I use AKKA with MySQL using the Java API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are orthogonal (Akka and MySQL), you can use what ever persistence API you fancy.